# AngularJS Post to MVC not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, post

How do I debug why MVC is returning 500 error when I try to post to my controller from AngularJS? No exceptions are thrown.

Here is my AngularJS code

```
var recordingRequest = {
    deviceSerial: 2160563840, 
    plannedStartTime: "2015-08-07T14:29", 
    recordingDuration: 60, 
    recordingDurationIsMinutes: true
}
```

The service that posts the data:

```
deviceAPI.addDeviceRecording = function (recordingRequest) {
    // Request data
    return $http.post("/devices/adddevicerecording/", recordingRequest);
}
```

And finally the MVC controller entry point:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddDeviceRecording(int deviceSerial, string plannedStartTime, int recordingDuration, bool recordingDurationIsMinutes)
{
}
```

Any breakpoints I put inside the `AddDeviceRecording` function never gets hit.  I know its getting part way there because it gives 500 rather than 404. If I change the `$http.post` to point to a random URL I get 404 instead.

Comment: your device serial is too high. the max value for ints in C# is 2,147,483,647, your device serial is 2,160,563,840. You need to change your datatypes.

Comment: I feel stupid now, thank you ! Please post as an answer so that I can accept - I do wish MVC provided you with some inclining as to why it cannot serialize JSON into POCOs etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your device serial is too high.

the max value for `Int32` in C# is 2,147,483,647, your device serial is 2,160,563,840.

You need to change your datatypes